# I receive cron email every 20 minutes but don't find the cron

Tags: cron

After I installed ssmtp I started receving the following emails:

```
Cron <smmsp@vps123456> test -x /etc/init.d/sendmail && /usr/share/sendmail/sendmail cron-msp
```

I looked at /etc/crontab and I deleted some lines that seemed to send these mails but I still receive them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically cron logs which jobs get executed so check `/var/log`

Then there are usually three  classes of cron jobs:

- personal cron specifications `crontab -e` stored in `/var/spool/cron`
- system cron job from `/etc/crontab` which also runs  the `/etc/cron.[daily|hourly|weekly|monthly]` scripts
- `/etc/cron.d/` drop in batches

Comment: Ok, in /etc/cron.d I had a task for sendmail which I removed.Thanks